# SAS merge on date and time

Tags: date, time, merge, format, sas

I am trying to merge two datasets based on date and time.

In both sets the date is date9. format and the time is time5. format.

I thought a simple merge such as below would suffice.

I am guessing that SAS is reading the date as a datetime and the time in seconds.

```
data test;
merge JRA_UK_July_spot (in=a)
UK_surveys_30plus (in=b);
by date time_num;
if a and b;
run;
```

I am getting no records in the merged table.

NOTE: There were 19517 observations read from the data set WORK.JRA_UK_JULY_SPOT.
NOTE: There were 114235 observations read from the data set WORK.UK_SURVEYS_30PLUS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 0 observations and 14 variables.

i know that there are records that should match.

from table a

```
time_num   date
9:07       01JUL2014
9:07       01JUL2014
```

from table b

```
date        time_num
01JUL2014   9:07
01JUL2014   9:07
01JUL2014   9:07
```

could it be something to do with the way the date/time is stored? for example could 9:07 be 9:07:34 and that's not what is matching with another that might be 9:07:11?

Comment: What appears to be the problem? Are you getting unexpected results, an error message, something else? Perhaps some details of what the issue is (perhaps with sample data and / or any error message) would help focus any responses.

Comment: Hi Amir. I've just edited the question as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: To test your theory about seconds, try displaying a few of the time values in your log, e.g. `put time_num time.;` then that should show you any seconds that are stored.

Comment: Alternatively just use the best12. format which would display the exact number being stored, i.e. the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1960.

Comment: Ahh yes. doing that shows values such as  3766.323
    6977.687 I am rubbish with formats. How can I just convert these times and dates to something that will ignore all the seconds?

Comment: Try making use of the hour() and minute() functions which just extract the minute and hour.

Comment: I did a rounding of the time to 60 and that appears to have resolved the problem. Thanks all.

Comment: @JamesAdams Please make an answer with that information (and a short example of the code that you used).  This is a good question to have in the database.

Comment: HI Joe. Done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty here is that the time is not being read as just hours and minutes but as seconds too - even though this is not displayed in the format.

To resolve this I simply rounded the sas time to the nearest 60 (ie the nearest minute) using the round function;

```
time_round=round(put(time_num, best12.), 60);
```

I then merged on time_round (which is a sastime in seconds from midnight eg 5940)

Doing this resolved the above merge issue.